# How to sync and save data to mysql (server side) from offline saved data from sqlite Flutter?

Tags: mysql, flutter, android-sqlite

I want to save user inputs in sqlite in Flutter offline and I will sync those data to mysql (php) when I am online. Can you guys suggest me 'How to' or useful links?

Comment: do you know how to use node.js with socket.io?

Comment: I don't know but I found how to use them. And is this the only solution Kenneth Li?

Comment: not the only solution but using socket.io you 'know' whether the app is 'actually online', and the synchronization of data can be bi-directional.